# Выборка из двух таблиц с UNION ALL и с сортировкой по id первой таблицы, то есть, остается порядок первой таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Делаю выборку из двух таблиц при помощи UNION ALL. В первой таблице хранятся названия видов работ с ценами по умолчанию. Во второй - те же названия видов работ с ценами, но уже добавленные пользователями.

Таблицы:

```html
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vid` text NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `izmer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `kategor` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vid` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `izmer` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `kategor` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `DayuDobro` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Вот пример запроса:

```html
$sql = "SELECT vid, AVG(price) price, izmer FROM (SELECT vid, price, izmer FROM table1 where kategor = 'kategor1'
               UNION ALL
               SELECT vid, price, izmer FROM table2 where kategor = 'kategor1') AS subquery GROUP BY vid";
```

На выходе получаю список работ со средней ценой по каждому виду работ.
**Проблема в том,** что сортировка происходит по полю 'vid' в алфавитном порядке и это 'ломает' список видов работ. **Я бы хотел сортировать по id первой таблицы, то есть, чтоб порядок записей оставался таким, как в table1**. Виды работ в table2 создаются динамически и периодически повторяются, поэтому и не получается отсортировать по id. Пожалуйста, помогите с этим вопросом. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы действительно хотите получить среднее ``цены по умолчанию`` и ``ценами,добавленными пользователями``?

Comment: По умолчанию - это цена от меня. В table2 цены от пользователей. Вывожу среднюю цену по каждому виду работ. Нужна сортировка по первой таблице, если такое возможно.

Comment: вас спрашивают, что сейчас цена средняя из вашей + пользователей. так и задумано? Мб вам надо среднюю пользователей, а если таковые отсутствуют то вашу?

Comment: чтобы сортировать по какому-либо полю, надо добавить соответствующую инструкцию `order by`. Порядок строк в таблице в целом не задан (в целом данные лежат в таблице физически упорядоченные по кластеризованному индексу (первичный ключ) и в большинстве случаев так и выведутся, ибо потому что будут прочитаны в этом порядке. но сортировка результата не гарантирована никак), если вам требуется явно вывести с какой то сортировкой, то надо явно ее явно и указать. Так что мб `order by vid` и решит ваш вопрос.

Comment: Средняя цена берется из моей цены (table1) и цен, которые указали пользователи (table2). В запросе это указано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
SELECT vid, AVG(price) price, max(izmer) izmer 
FROM 
   (
     SELECT id, vid, price, izmer FROM table1 where kategor = 'kategor1'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 0 as id, vid, price, izmer FROM table2 where kategor = 'kategor1'
   ) AS subquery 
GROUP BY vid 
ORDER BY max(id);
```

Я добавил в запрос `max(izmer) izmer`  иначе будет ошибка группировки.

UPD1.  Поясню на примере. Допустим такие исходные данные
Table1

| id | vid | price | izmer | kategor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Вид1 | 100 | руб | kategor1 |
| 11 | Вид2 | 1200 | руб | kategor1 |

Table2

| id | UserID | vid | price | izmer | kategor | date | DayuDobro |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121 | 1 | Вид1 | 120 | руб | kategor1 | 2023-05-20 | 1 |
| 122 | 2 | Вид1 | 140 | руб | kategor1 | 2023-05-30 | 1 |

Внутренний запрос

```
 SELECT id, vid, price, izmer FROM table1 where kategor = 'kategor1'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 0 as id, vid, price, izmer FROM table2 where kategor = 'kategor1'
```

Даст такой результат

| id | vid | price | izmer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | Вид1 | 100 | руб |
| 11 | Вид2 | 1200 | руб |
| 0 | Вид1 | 120 | руб |
| 0 | Вид1 | 140 | руб |

Т.е. данные из table1 будут со значением id>0, данные из table2 будут со значением id=0. Выражением max(id) выбираем id из подзапроса. Он, очевидно будет значением из table1.

```
SELECT vid, AVG(price) price, max(izmer) izmer, max(id) table1_id
FROM 
   (
     SELECT id, vid, price, izmer FROM table1 where kategor = 'kategor1'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 0 as id, vid, price, izmer FROM table2 where kategor = 'kategor1'
   ) AS subquery 
GROUP BY vid 
ORDER BY max(id);
```

Результат запроса

| vid | price | izmer | table1_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Вид2 | 1200.0000 | руб | 11 |
| Вид1 | 120.0000 | руб | 21 |

При этом в выходном результате поле max(id) table1_id - не нужно. Его можно убрать из FROM. Но в ORDER BY используем.

[Пример здесь](https://dbfiddle.uk/aAzY8D3N)

Comment: Попробовал запрос ниже и он работает, но не уверен, что это правильно: `$sql = "SELECT id, vid, AVG(price) price, izmer FROM (SELECT id, vid, price, izmer FROM moscow_new where kategor = 'Земляные работы'
               UNION ALL
               SELECT id, vid, price, izmer FROM moscow_price_test where kategor = 'Земляные работы' AND DayuDobro = '1') AS subquery GROUP BY vid ORDER BY id";`

Comment: Ваш запрос работает! Но я не совсем понимаю как. Не могли бы Вы объяснить логику? Спасибо большое!